# Files are not uploaded

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I have simple form

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

and on same page I am checking $_FILES as `if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_REQUEST);
        echo "</pre>";
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_Files);
        echo "</pre>";
        die; }`

I am not able to see any data in $_FILES. I have checked sever settings

```
file_uploads = On,upload_max_filesize = 64M, max_file_uploads = 20
```

I am using wamp server. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to write `$_FILES` in upper case instead of `$_Files`

Comment: can you also show the code you use to save the file - ie: process the upload?

Comment: @Object Manipulator OMG that was problem. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You write `print_r($_Files);` instead of `print_r($_FILES);` !